# Nibble Restriction to 0-9

Tags: converters, restriction, nibble

Hello fellow Programmers,

int main()
int n;

```
scanf("%d", &n ,);
printf("nibble =  %d%d%d%d", (n/8)%2, (n/4)%2, (n/2)%2 , n%2 );

return 0;}
```

I´ve build this code so far, the code converts a decimal value into a nibble.

It works but i have questions regarding on how to restrict the input to 0-9, 
without using if statemens. Is there any possiblty to do that and if how ?
At the moment the code uses 0 - 15 decimals.And can you please give me an example or explain to me so i can understand it .

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible without using conditions

but tell us what your program should do if a decimal >9 is putted in?

```
scanf("%d", &n ,);
if ((n>=0) && (n<10))
  printf("nibble =  %d%d%d%d", (n/8)%2, (n/4)%2, (n/2)%2 , n%2 );
else
  printf("err: input out of range");
```

Comment: but can you still give me a possible example even with conditions maybe please ?

Comment: i added the example above.   by the way,  you declared n as "int" -- its  a signed var in most compilers. if you write "unsigned int" you can remove the first sub condition ( n>=0).

Comment: nice thank you so the && in the middle of the second line safes both inputs of n>0 and n<10 right?

Comment: **&&** is a logical **AND**.  so the condition on the  left **and** right side must be true to get a true as a result